# how can i determine which dropdownlistfor caused postback in mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

i have 2 dropdownlistfor in the view .. every one of them can cause postback
i want to get the name of the one when cause postback

```
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        Owner</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OwnerId, new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(Model.CallForPaperJournalOwnersList, "OwnerId", "Owner"), new { onchange = "submit();" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        Journal Code:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.JournalCode, new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(Model.JournalsWithCallForPaperHtmlList, "JournalCode", "JournalCode"), new { onchange = "submit();" })

                </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case ... i would use an id :

```
   <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        Owner</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OwnerId, new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(Model.CallForPaperJournalOwnersList, "OwnerId", "Owner"), new { id = "btnsave2" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        Journal Code:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.JournalCode, new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(Model.JournalsWithCallForPaperHtmlList, "JournalCode", "JournalCode"), new { id= "btnchange2" })

                </td>
            </tr>
```

and call the id

```
     $('#btnsave1').click(function (event) {
//do stuff here 
}
```

If you want to do an operation on more than one DDL dont use onclick.. Use :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OwnerId, new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(Model.CallForPaperJournalOwnersList, "OwnerId", "Owner"), new { @class = "myclass" })
```

and in jquery just go :

```
 $('.myclass').click(function (event) {
//do stuff here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project i am doing like this

I fill my state dropdownl with country id like this

this is my Dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "ID", "Name"), "select", new { @ID = "ddlCountry", @class = "text", Style = "width: 150px;", onchange = "javascript:cascadingdropdown();" })
```

i create a javascript function like this it's below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cascadingdropdown() {            
        var countryID = $('#countryID').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/City/State",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { countryId: countryID },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#stateID").empty();
                $("#stateID").append("<option value='0'>--Select State--</option>");
                $.each(data, function (index, optiondata) {
                    alert(optiondata.StateName);
                    $("#stateID").append("<option value='" + optiondata.ID + "'>" + optiondata.StateName + "</option>");
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Faild To Retrieve states.');
            }

        });
    }
```

i think this will help you...